# sentence structure for "Geht Ihnen Ihr Job auf den Wecker?""

Tags: sentence-structure

I have come across this sentence:

> Geht Ihnen Ihr Job auf den Wecker?

Can someone please tell me why both "Ihnen" and "Ihr" are used here together? I just couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Got the Xing e-mail? ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Geht Ihnen x auf den Wecker?

means *Is x getting up your nose?* So *x* is subject and *Ihnen* is object in dative case.

Now the question is about the person's job. That's *Ihr Job*. And all together gives you:

> Geht Ihnen Ihr Job auf den Wecker?

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: My pleasure! If you find a good question that helps you learning: upvote. If you get an helpful answer: upvote. That's how we thank each other here. ;) So no need to write that in questions or comments - it will be deleted. ;)